# C: Указатели и квадратные скобки

Tags: c, указатели

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от квадратных скобок в этой строке кода?

```
(*buf)[j] = (*buf)[j + 1];
```

Comment: *(*buf + j) = *(*buf + j + 1); (Если buf - это то, что я думаю)

Answer (score 0):

чуть более общий случай:

```
int elementSize = sizeof(ELEMENT_TYPE);
*(*buf + j * elementSize) = *(*buf + (j + 1) * elementSize);
```

Где ELEMENT_TYPE - тип элементов в буфере.

Уточнение с размером элементов имеет смысл для типов размер которых не равен 1 байту.